# Center text on NavigationPage's TitleView: it is slightly offset due to back button at left

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

hi i am trying to center the text in the navigation bar but it is centered in relation to this feedback button

here is my code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Paypal.profile">
    
    <NavigationPage.TitleView>
            <Label Text="Préférences" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"/>
        </NavigationPage.TitleView>

    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!"
                VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
                HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

there is my problem
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IxUqV.jpg)

and what i want :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mzc7O.jpg)

Comment: HorizontalTextAlignment centers the Text within the Label.  HorizontalOptions controls the alignment of the Label within its parent container

Comment: @jason yeah i try it but without result

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the back button and add a custom back button.

1.remove the back button with code:

```
   NavigationPage.HasBackButton="False"
```

2.Add a custom image and add `TapGestureRecognizer` event for the back button.

```
<NavigationPage.TitleView>
    <AbsoluteLayout>
        <Image AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0, 0.5" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional" WidthRequest="20" HeightRequest="20"
               Source="back.png">
            <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped"/>
            </Image.GestureRecognizers>
        </Image>
        <Label Text="MyTitle" FontSize="20" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5, 0.5" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional" />
    </AbsoluteLayout>
</NavigationPage.TitleView>
```

The whole sample code is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="FormApp0706.TestPage"
             
             NavigationPage.HasBackButton="False"
             >

    <NavigationPage.TitleView>
        <AbsoluteLayout>
            <Image AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0, 0.5" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional" WidthRequest="20" HeightRequest="20"
                   Source="back.png">
                <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped"/>
                </Image.GestureRecognizers>
            </Image>
            <Label Text="MyTitle" FontSize="20" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5, 0.5" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional" />
        </AbsoluteLayout>
    </NavigationPage.TitleView>

    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!"
                VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
                HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```